# mod ssl error during ssl installation

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

Server Environment
AWS EC2, Ubuntu 14.04LTS, LAMP

443 Port is enabled from security group. Server is listening to 443 port.

I have purchased SSL from cheapsslsecurity.com and followed following step.

step 1 : create a bundle

cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > PositiveSSL.ca-bundle

Step 2 : Edit site conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/domaincom

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ./ssls/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile ./ssls/STAR_domain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile ./ssls/PositiveSSL.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>
```

Step 3 : Restart the server

Then following error is coming :

```
[Sat Apr 23 10:50:14.668246 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 32733] AH02238: Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Sat Apr 23 10:50:14.668348 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 32733] SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
[Sat Apr 23 10:50:14.668354 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 32733] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

With respect to above error, I did some research as follows

1. Same value is coming for both

   openssl x509 -noout -in STAR_domain_com.crt | openssl md5

   openssl rsa -noout -in server.key | openssl md5
2. put following line in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

   SSLCertificateChainFile ./ssls/PositiveSSL.ca-bundle
3. Many more things listed on www.google.com :( 
   Each time i restart the apache, getting the same error.

Anything out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SSLCACertificateFile` instead of `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile ./ssls/server.key
SSLCertificateFile ./ssls/STAR_domain_com.crt
SSLCACertificateFile ./ssls/PositiveSSL.ca-bundle
```

Also, be sure that they are in the correct directories accessible by Apache. You can also transfer your certificates to `/etc/ssl/private` to double check.